# Откат mysql запросов при возникновении ошибки запроса в последовательности

Tags: php, sql

Доброй ночи. Как правильно обработать следующую ситуацию:

```
function Example($new_login, $old_login, $new_lastname)
{
  $Query1 = Mysql_query('UPDATE `user` SET `login`='{$new_login}' ');
  if(mysql_affected_rows() == false) die('Здесь произошла ошибка, не удалось обновить логин в баз');

  $Query2 = Mysql_query('UPDATE `user` SET `lastname`='{$new_lastname}' ');
 if($Query2 == true) die('Всё ок, все запросы выполнились');
 // Не удалось обновить имя пользователя в базе, нужно вернуть старый логин на место!!

$Query1 = Mysql_query('UPDATE `user` SET `login`='{$old_login}' ');
// Вроде-бы вернули, НО! Что делать если этот запрос тоже по каким-то причинам не выполнился?
}
```

Интересует ответ на вопрос: как откатить предыдущие запросы, если следующий запрос не выполнился, ведь этот запрос тоже может не выполниться?  Некая матрёшка получается, ну или рекурсия... )

Comment: @Vladimir_7878, как по мне, нужно предотвращать подобное, а не искать решение на исправления. Если я не прав, поправьте меня. :)

Comment: @Vladimir_7878, специально для этого придумали транзакции. Запросы, обернутые в транзакцию, откатываются в случае провала транзакции.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-transactions.html https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)

И почитайте обязательно про Isolation Level, чтобы представлять чуть подробнее, как транзакция выглядит для третьестороннего наблюдателя.

Answer (score 1):

Одна табличка, а почему не выполнить эти 3 запроса в одном? Там в случае неправильности запрос не выполнится вообще.